# Visual Studio 2019 while opening aspx file, code is not displaying at first time

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio, telerik, visual-studio-2019

I just installed Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise and Telerik Web UI components.

When I opening a aspx file, page is not loading. After I switching to another page or another app and switch back to that file code is displaying in that time. This is only happening to .aspx files. While aspx.vb or aspx.cs pages are loaded correctly.

This is how it looks;

[image: vs2019error]

I repaired Visual Studio but problem contiunes.
What may causing this to happen? I couldn't find a solution by myself or online.

I observed that it happens on my second monitor, when I switch the VS to my laptop's main screen it is not happening.

[image: settings]

Which options should I close for solve this?

Comment: I've been experiencing weird glitches in VS2019's support for `.aspx` files lately too - but never anything as bad as this. Do you have any third-party extensions installed? Have you tried enabling/disabling VS's hardware-accelerated UI?

Comment: Also, I recommend creating a new VM and doing a stock install of VS in there (and *don't* sign-in with a Personalization account, activate it with a product-key instead) so you have a "known good" install of VS you can use whenever it breaks on your desktop.

Comment: Does this happen even on new project with ASPX files?

Comment: @Dai I look at your recommend and find the cause. Could you check my question again I edited it.

Comment: @Martheen Yes, It happens

Comment: Disabling both rich client and graphics hardware usually works for your case

Comment: Sounds like you have dodgy NVIDIA Optimus drivers fighting with your laptop's CPU's Intel GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities (requires restart)" fixed it for me.